# Grab video information from Youtube Channel store it in MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, youtube

I need a way to grab information such as title, description, URL from a specific channel and then store it in a database.

The trickiest part seems to be formatting the information I get back from the youtube api. I am having a hard time breaking it apart and getting what I need.

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$username.'/uploads';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Above is what I am doing.

The vimeo way of doing things seems so much easier.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What do you get from the above code?

Comment: http://justpaste.it/28p6 This is var_dump($xml)

Comment: It is a slightly awkward format it seems to me, but I was able to parse it out without too much trouble. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$username="riotgamesinc";
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$username.'/uploads';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml->entry as $video) {
    echo $video->title;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $video->content;
    echo "<br />";
    $attributes = $video->link[0]->attributes();
    echo $attributes['href'];
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using xml, but I find JSON a little easier to work with:

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json';
  $content = file_get_contents($url);
  $json = json_decode($content, true);

  print_r($json);
?>
```

Then you could use anything really to display it, but I was working with Handbars.js last night on a twitter feed and it was pretty easy.  I wish I had the code with me so I could give you an example, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I ever need to use JSON this way I will use this as a reference.